# Vitest : Unable to find an error message provided by yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, formik, vitest

I've got an error since yesterday. I'm testing the register feature, the username input. If the user field contains less than 5 characters, an error message is supposed to be shown, but I keep getting this error :

"TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: The username must be at least 5 characters.. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible."

I'm using formik and yup for forms submissions. I've searched in stack overflow and found this post talking about a possible issue with the new version of jest and incompatibility with formik and yup : [Yup and Formik not validating form when testing with Jest and React Testing Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73008275/yup-and-formik-not-validating-form-when-testing-with-jest-and-react-testing-libr)

I've tested it manually on my localhost to see if it works, and it does, so I don't really know what to do now.

Here's my test code :

```
import { test, expect } from "vitest";
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup} from "@testing-library/react";
import Register from "./Register";
import { MemoryRouter, Route, Router } from "react-router-dom";

test("Register component renders correctly", () => {
  
  const { getByTestId, getByLabelText, getByText } = render(<MemoryRouter><Register /></MemoryRouter>);

  test("renders the registration form", () => {
    expect(getByText("MAISON PLISSON")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(getByLabelText("Username:")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(getByLabelText("Email:")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(getByLabelText("Password:")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(getByLabelText("Confirm password:")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(getByTestId("sign-up-button")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  cleanup();

});

test("displays error message when username is too short", async () => {
  const { findByText, getByTestId, getByLabelText, getByText } = render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Register />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  const usernameInput = getByTestId("username-input");
  const submitButton = getByTestId("sign-up-button");

  fireEvent.change(usernameInput, { target: { value: "foo" } });
  fireEvent.click(submitButton);

  const errorMessage = await getByText("The username must be at least 5 characters.");
  expect(errorMessage).toBeInTheDocument();

  cleanup();
});
```

And if you need the complete register component, there's my github links for the component itself and his custom hook :

https://github.com/Sonalpt/mpb-frontend-demo/tree/master/src/pages/Register

That's all guys, thx in advance for any hint on this !